# XPath to find anchor with no text?

Tags: xpath

I have a couple of anchor tags which have no text, so `<a href="www.something.com">no text here</a>`, how do I find those anchors with no text?

I've tried this but it's returning nothing:

```
global $post;
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($post->post_content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a[string-length(.) = 0]');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $remove_elements[] = $node->getAttribute('href');
}
return $remove_elements;
```

The html looks like this.

```
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.riverisland.com/women/sale/accessories/Black-and-white-faux-fur-collar-646464" target="_blank"></a>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if a node has no text(), you can use string-length() which excepts a node. In this case '.' is a reference to current element.

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

You can do

```
//a[string-length(.) = 0]
```

Comment: Hi, no sorry, I need to find an anchor with <a href="www.data.com">no text here</a>.

Comment: Thanks, that sounded like it should have worked but it's not, I've updated my question with more details :)

Comment: Ah, got it working, I wasn't paying attention and was echoing the wrong variable... sigh, I need sleep. Thank you.